# How to remove U+FE6B (﹫) from a string?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, trim

I ran into a problem when the structure of the game chat of cs2 got changed.

I already changed the code accordingly, but for some reason I can't seem to get these lines of code to work:

```
/* removal of the team-chat location info. */
if (chatType == ChatType.Team)
{
    var idx = namePart.LastIndexOf('﹫'); // uFE6B

    if (idx != -1)
        namePart = namePart.Substring(0, idx).Trim();
}
```

Filtering like this works:

```
/* filter out the massage */
if (!l.Contains("[ALL]") && !l.Contains("﹫")) // uFE6B
    continue;
```

This is what the line in the log looks like:

[image]

I already tried using a Unicode escape sequence, but no luck.

Comment: `string result = string.Concat(text.Where(c => c >= 32 && c <= 127));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *quite* sure what you want, but you can use regex to if you want to remove that character from strings:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "Your ﹫ string with ﹫ character";

// Regex pattern to match the character '﹫' (Unicode U+FE6B)
string pattern = @"\uFE6B";

// Replace the matched character with an empty string
string result = Regex.Replace (input, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

just fixed it myself... after posting the question I realized its looking to trim in `chatType.Team` and not `namePart`

like my grandpa always said:

> Those who can read have a clear advantage